# Смена prop checked radio инпута по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть радио инпут. Возможно ли по клику на этот инпут менять checked?
Если у кого то есть готовое решение, прошу поделиться!
Пытался что то вроде такого:

```
$(document).on('click','input',function(e){
    var th = $(this);
    if (th.prop('checked')){
       th.prop('false');
    }
});
```

не вышло....

Comment: Покажи `html`..

Comment: @Air по идеи  при нажатии на Radio у него и так меняется checked на true :)

Answer (score 1):

Что то типо того?  Как вариант:

```js
$(document).on('click','input[type="text"]',function(e){
    var th = $(this).data("id");
    var radio = $(document).find("#"+th);
    
   if(!radio.is(':checked')) { 
    radio.prop("checked", true);
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input style="width:250px;cursor: pointer;" data-id="a" value="Нажми на меня и я выделю Radio A" type="text"> </br>

   A: <input id="a" type="radio"  name="test">
   B: <input id="b" type="radio" name="test">
```